# Optimally directing switches for a random walk

Tags: pr.probability, co.combinatorics, random-walks, algorithms

**If you are sometimes called upon directing a random walk in a directed graph, how should you direct it so as to maximize the probability it goes where you want?**

### Formal statement

More specifically, suppose you are given a directed graph $G$ with edge weights, two designated vertices $s$ and $t$, and a subset of the vertices $S$.  The edges weights represent the transition probabilities of the random walk, the vertex $s$ the start, the vertex $t$ the target, and the set $S$ the set of switches.  You are guaranteed that the weights on the out-edges of any node are non-negative and sum to one, that $t$ is absorbing (i.e., $t$ has one out-edge directed towards itself), and that the out-degree of any vertex in $S$ is exactly two.

A random walk is taken on $G$, starting at $s$.  For any given vertex not in $S$, the weight on an out-edge is the probability that the walk will travel in that direction.  Every time that the walk reaches a switch (a vertex in $S$), you are allowed to choose which of the two edges the walk will travel along (and you are allowed probabilistic strategies).  How should you direct the path if you want to maximize the probability that the walk ends up at your target $t$?

### Questions

I am most interested in this as an algorithmic question.  How fast can you find the optimal strategy with respect to the size of the graph?  My specific application has about 100 switches among 200 vertices in a fairly sparse graph (say out-degree bounded above by 6).

But we can also ask purely mathematical questions.  For example, my intuition says (and I can hand-wave a proof) that there exists an optimal strategy that is deterministic in the sense that it always chooses the same direction for a given switch and this direction does not depend on the initial vertex $s$.  Is this actually true?

Also, is there a sense in which the optimal strategy needs to "coordinate" among the switches?  That is, is there a local optimum that is not a global optimum?

### Notes

*A note on connectivity*: we may assume that the graph is sufficiently connected.  If not, we can identify all vertices that cannot be reached from the start node, as well as all of those that cannot reach the target node, into a single, absorbing fail state.  We may assume the start node is not the fail node.

Comment: Is the number of steps fixed?

Comment: Also, can I make two different choices if the switch is reached twice?

Comment: No, the walk is infinite.  However, note that once the walk reaches an absorbing vertex (such as the target $t$), it stays there.

Comment: Yes, you may make a separate choice each time a switch is reached. My intuition says you won't, but I'll be happily surprised if you prove me wrong.

Comment: Here's my proof sketch of "determinism".  Look at a strategy as a probability distribution on choices, where repeated choices are treated separately.  Then, by the usual argument, there is an optimal strategy that is pure (any mixed strategy is a convex combination of pure strategies).  Now suppose the walk reaches vertex $v$ at time $a$ and time $b$ and you made different decisions.  Why would you do that -- if the decision at $b$ was optimal, then you should make the same decision at $a$.  Finally, it shouldn't matter where you start because all that matters is where you are now.

Comment: One hack could be to initialize both out edges from each switch with a nonzero weight, say 0.5.  Then for each switch sink compute the probability of ending up at the target.  For each switch, upvote the outgoing edge which has the higher probability of ending up at the target (and similarly downvote the other edge).  Iterate.  Maybe this will converge to switch edge weights near 0.0 and 1.0; if so then discretizing to 0 and 1 will give decisions which are in some sense locally optimal.


Comment: @optima: Yes, that seems like a plausible heuristic.  Strategies like that motivate my question regarding local versus global optima.  I am really interested only in a global optimum.  But if they're one and the same, then everything's great.  (Unfortunately, my experience tells me that one should rarely assume local optima are global optima also.)

Comment: By convexity there is indeed a deterministic optimal strategy: The probability of success is a linear function on the space of strategies, so takes its extremal values at extremal points.

Comment: Is the graph infinite? If so, we can truncate it by replacing the outside of a large ball by a sink. 

If the number of steps is bounded by $n$, then we can recursively compute the probability of success and optimal strategy in $O(n|G|)$. These should converge to an optimal strategy for unbounded time.

Comment: @Omer: That proves that there is a pure strategy (as indicated in one of my comments above).  Unfortunately, I seem to have co-opted "deterministic", which often means the same thing as "pure", into a stronger notion.  A pure strategy in this context always makes a decision to either 100% go one way or 100% go the other way.  My notion of "deterministic" adds the condition that it makes the same decision every time it approaches a switch (a pure strategy need not do that) and that this doesn't depend on the starting node.

Comment: @Omer: The graph is finite, as I am interested in an algorithm.  I guess you're right that you can compute optimal strategies for the time-bounded case in $O(n \abs{G})$.  How fast does it converge?  (Is it completely obvious that it *does* converge to the optimal strategy?  Hmm.)

Comment: @ Omer: First, you change the equations, not the solutions in the linear way when you manipulate probabilities. Second, the convergence can be terribly slow. Indeed, let's combine all the vertices from which you cannot reach the target into one absorbing vertex $f$ (if there are no vertices like that, you end up at $t$ with probability $1$ no matter what). Assume that there is one switch that either sends you to a fork between $t$ and $m$ (1/2 for any decent number of steps), or sends you to a long path to $t$ with a lot of backtracking edges, so the expected time to reach $t$ is $5^{100}$.

Comment: determinism (or more precisely, a time homogeneous strategy) follows from the Markov property for the process. 

Comment: @fedja: I believe that the target probability is in fact linear on the right space of coordinates, one for each pure strategy.  By "pure strategy" I mean a complete description of whether to switch one way or the other in every possible state, with a separate state for every possible way of getting to a place.  (For example, suppose you have a switch with options X and Y.  Then a pure strategy would tell you what to do in all of the possible ways of getting there: X, Y, XX, XY, YX, ...)  You are correct of course that the convergence could be exponentially poor in the size of the graph.

Comment: @Omer: Yes of course.  Thanks for the correct choice of words ("time homogeneous").

Comment: To solve a simpler problem, what if you forget the weights and consider only the question of setting switch states so that there is a directed path from $s$ to $t$.  Does the solution need to coordinate switches in this simpler case?  This might help with the question about local vs global optimality in the weighted case.


Comment: @optima: I don't know what it means for a 0/1-valued function to have a local but not global optimum.

Comment: @Rex: "I don't know what it means for a 0/1-valued function to have a local but not global optimum."  Then what did you mean by "That is, is there a local optimum that is not a global optimum?" in the original question?

Comment: ----"I believe that the target probability is in fact linear on the right space of coordinates"----. Actually, if you consider only time-independent strategies, then it is a ratio if two polylinear forms in switch parameters. But, even if you forget "the ratio", finding the global maximum of a general polylinear form in the cube is not easy at all. Optima's link suggests the same. There is a faint hope that your form is somehow special though.

Comment: @optima: In the original question, I am maximizing a probability, which is between 0 and 1, that is, in the closed interval $[0, 1]$.  If we just care whether or not there is a path, that appears to be maximizing a function that takes only the values 0 (if there is no path) and 1 (if there is a path) themselves, that is, the endpoints of the interval.  But perhaps you mean something different.

Comment: @fedja: I know that in those coordinates it isn't linear.  But it is linear in other coordinates, which shows the maximum is at a corner, which you then use the Markov property on to show that the optimum is actually at a time-invariant strategy.  But then if you switch coordinates to the ones you're analyzing, the function isn't linear anymore, which happens because the change of coordinates map isn't linear itself.  Regarding maximization: yes, that's the hope.  The motivation I'm working with is that *I* can't figure out how to encode any sort of coordination/computation in this problem.

Comment: @Rex: I guess I meant looking for two switch configurations which both connect $s$ to $t$, and where you can't get from one configuration to the other configuration by flipping single switches at a time unless $t$ becomes unreachable from $s$ at some point.  These two configurations would be in different 'islands' of the solution space, and this is the kind of locality I was talking about.

Comment: @optima: That is a very reasonable notion of locality.  I'm sorry I didn't think of it.

Comment: @optima: And I think that locality cannot occur.  Suppose two different assignments connect $s$ and $t$, through paths $p$ and $q$ respectively.  Look at the last place in $p$ where it goes through a switch that is in the opposite position for the $q$ path.  You can safely switch the $q$ path there, because no later switches in $p$'s tail disagree.  Repeat until the $q$ path is identical with the $p$ path and then switch any irrelevant switches.

Comment: @fedja: I made no claim about the rate of convergence, which of course can be very bad.

by setting 0/1 initial conditions for n=0, we get lower and upper bounds, so it is easy to know how close we are to the optimal solution after a given number of steps.

Also, we can skip times we outside $S$, and reduce the graph to a Markov chain on $S$, where at each place we choose from two (or several) distributions.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simple stochastic games problem, but for only one player, and there is a polynomial-time algorithm for it based on linear programming, which is described in Anne Condon's paper "On Algorithms for Simple Stochastic Games." Look in this paper for the linear programming algorithm for SSG's with no min vertices. In one of her papers on simple stochastic games, Condon does indeed prove that the setting of the switches is independent of the start node, and that in the optimal strategy, the switch settings never need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: apparently I'm linking to a paper that has a different definition of 'switch'

The reachability problem is NP-complete for unweighted directed switch graphs.

http://www.springerlink.com/content/f2722481747l2170/

This means that in the weighted case it is NP hard to even find switch settings that can reach the target from the starting vertex, let alone reach the target with maximum probability.

Comment: Sounds fishy. Go back from $t$ and see from where you can reach it, expanding the set $S$. If you see a switch that can reach into the current version of $S$, just point it there and add it to $S$. Perhaps, the notions of a switch are different or they talk about full connectivity rather than reaching a given vertex. 

Comment: Yes, switch means something different there.

Comment: @Re your edit: it's understandable that this paper might be related.  I feel that I have one reasonable notion of what a switch means in a directed graph, and they have another one.  Theirs is another reasonable notion, primarily motivated by the fact that trains cannot make very sharp turns, and so physical train switches can only be used "in one direction".

Comment: I'm sorry, have we convinced ourselves this is NP hard? I remember thinking about this problem around Christmas and that was my belief then though I have no expertise here. 

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.